# MySQL vs PHP fread to get a single value (benchmark)

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update users when they get behind by a version.  I pull them into a PHP file & react accordingly

My call is this:

```
SELECT * FROM users JOIN version WHERE user_id= (the user loading the page)
if($user_version != $version_version) { update }
```

Then if user_version doesn't match version_version, I update.

Would it be faster to this?

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = (the user loading the page)
$ver = file_get_contents("version.txt");
if($ver != $user_version) { update }
```

Comment: Why not benchmark for yourself, but 1 database query + 1 if test versus 1 database query + 1 file access + 1 if test looks a bit of a no brainer.... as long as you JOIN with an ON clause to get a single row retrieval, and have properly indexed tables

Comment: What did you index, how did you index it? Is query caching enabled etc?